# HTML/CSS dropright submenu item overlaps (doesn't render properly) with text on the page background

Tags: html, css, menu

In `HTML` page I have a navigation menu that when hover(mouse over) above some menu items, a submenu/dropdown menu appears. Then moving mouse above some of the submenu's items another submenu appears/dropright submenu. To understand the concept, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvozar/CDx9j/1/).

Now, try to hover above menu item `Categories`->`All`->`IT`, and you can see that item `Programming` is somehow overlapped with text on the page/background. And item after it can not be accessed then.

See CSS styles. What is causing this, and how to prevent that overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ovikOXu/1/edit)**, comment position: relative; out:

```
 #homeMainContent #pages {
// position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Please let me know if this works for you

Comment: thanks, yes it works, I overlooked such simple thing

Answer (score 2):

Just set a high `z-index` on your `.droprightMenu` and that will place the dropdown above that text

ex:

```
.droprightMenu {
    display: none;
    /* hide the sub menus */
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 100; /*ADD Z-INDEX*/ 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `z-index: 99` to `.dropdownMenu`, it will be fine.

See : http://jsfiddle.net/CDx9j/4/

To understand : your `#pages` element use a position relative, such as your dropdown menu. As the `#pages` element comes after the menu in the HTML float, it will come over the menu.